# SQL select accross 3 tables reusing subselect

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I need to get some rows from WatchDog table.
Simplified table script is as follows

```
Use Question
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Errors](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WatchDogId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ErrName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StopperCode](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Watchdog](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ErrFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
GO

INSERT [dbo].[StopperCode] ([Id], [ErrorCode]) VALUES (1, N'Stop1')
INSERT [dbo].[StopperCode] ([Id], [ErrorCode]) VALUES (2, N'Stop2')
INSERT [dbo].[Watchdog] ([Id], [Name], [ErrFlag]) VALUES (1, N'Dog1', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Watchdog] ([Id], [Name], [ErrFlag]) VALUES (2, N'Dog2', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Watchdog] ([Id], [Name], [ErrFlag]) VALUES (3, N'Dog3', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Errors] ([Id], [WatchDogId], [ErrName], [TimeStamp]) VALUES (1, 2, N'Stop1 because blabla', CAST(N'2018-08-07T12:18:02.9939600+02:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
INSERT [dbo].[Errors] ([Id], [WatchDogId], [ErrName], [TimeStamp]) VALUES (2, 2, N'ErrSmall', CAST(N'2018-08-07T12:20:21.3287921+02:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
INSERT [dbo].[Errors] ([Id], [WatchDogId], [ErrName], [TimeStamp]) VALUES (3, 2, N'Stop2 bla bla', CAST(N'2018-08-07T12:20:39.3095900+02:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
INSERT [dbo].[Errors] ([Id], [WatchDogId], [ErrName], [TimeStamp]) VALUES (4, 3, N'Stop1 bla bla', CAST(N'2018-08-07T12:20:59.2625851+02:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
INSERT [dbo].[Errors] ([Id], [WatchDogId], [ErrName], [TimeStamp]) VALUES (5, 3, N'ErrSmall', CAST(N'2018-08-07T12:21:57.6044187+02:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
GO
```

I need to get failed tasks from WatchDog filtered with datetime (return only those that lets say in last hour failed not more than 2 times) and whose last error is not in StopperCode table. Stopper code contains only beggining of error message.

I would like to get Errors.Id=3 based on conditions in query executed on this sample set. 2 should not be returned since last error is in StopperCode table. If there were more than 2 (not from StopperCode) errors for WatchDogId=3 in last hour it should not be returned either.
Now I can write some awkward select with sub selects, but I'd like to do this somehow more efficiently. And I would also like not to do the same select twice.

Comment: It's great that you posted sample data as DDL+DML, but it would be even better if you could also post your desired result and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Desired results are described briefly since there is no need to specify exactly what I want. For the sake of simlicity WatchDogId is enough as a result in answer. What I tried is quite unreadable and wasteful on the first sight. So I rather left it out of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, below query will work for you.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WatchDogId ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RNO
,*
FROM [#Errors] E
)
SELECT C.ErrName, C.WatchDogId, W.Name
FROM CTE C
INNER JOIN [#Watchdog] W ON C.WatchDogId = W.Id
LEFT JOIN [#StopperCode] S ON C.ErrName LIKE S.ErrorCode+'%'
WHERE C.RNO=1
AND S.Id IS NULL
```

Since I didn't get your last 1 hr condition, I left it for you.

**Result:**

```
ErrName   WatchDogId    Name
ErrSmall  3             Dog3
```